# Class File Editor Redundant Source not found

Tags: java, eclipse, axis

While debugging the code of my project(in Eclipse), I saw this message

```
Class File Editor
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source not found

The source attachment does not contain the source for the file Call.class
You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached source below

(Button)--->Change Attached Source...
```

When I press the button `Change Attached Source...`, it asks about the location containing the source for `axis.jar` (but `Call.class` is inside the `axis.jar`). I already have the `axis.jar` in my Java Build Path for sure, but even locating again, still the problem exists. Is it because I'm making some redundancy for debugging a class or because I have the `axis.jar` in more than one library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, you have .jar file but you don't have source code attached to it. you need java decompiler to see the source and you can also do debug. you have to install the decompler plugin ( http://jd.benow.ca/jd-eclipse/update) to see the source.

**Edit:** It is working fine for rt.jar (as per my observation), If you get above error even after installation of plugin.. you need some configuration as given below:

```
In Eclipse >>> window > preferences > General > Editors > File Associations > 
 1) Choose .class with out source from file types and chooese
 2) In Associated editors ..> add  > Choose "Class File Editor" > clic ok.
then set it as default.
```